# How do I upload Pillow processed image to S3 on Django?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library

I'm trying below code that I wrote but it's throwing an error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated

```
def upload_img(request):
    maxsize = (1024, 1024)
    im = Image.open(request.FILES['image'])
    im.thumbnail(maxsize)
    img_name = 'test.jpg'
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.put_object(
        Bucket=settings.AWS_S3_DEV_IMG_BUCKET,
        Key=img_name,
        Body=im.save(img_name, "JPEG"),
        ContentType='image/jpeg',
    )
```

ERROR:

```
'ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Body, value: None, type: <type 'NoneType'>, valid types: <type 'str'>, <type 'bytearray'>, file-like object
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Image.save()` method doesn't return an image, it [saves it to disk (or buffer) and returns `None`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save). That is why boto is complaining about `NoneType` parameters.

You want to save the data to some temporary buffer and then pass that off to boto. For example:

```
buffer = io.BytesIO()
im.save(buffer, "JPEG")
buffer.seek(0) # rewind pointer back to start
s3.put_object(
    Bucket=settings.AWS_S3_DEV_IMG_BUCKET,
    Key=img_name,
    Body=buffer,
    ContentType='image/jpeg',
)
```